# PL/SQL: convertir varchar a hora para luego obtener diferencia

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Tengo guardado en una tabla un `varchar` que representa una hora, por ejemplo '23:30'. Lo que quiero hacer es convertir ese valor a hora y luego calcular la diferencia con respecto a `sysdate`... ¿Habrá alguna forma de hacerlo?

Convierto la variable con `to_date` pero muestra una fecha que no tiene nada que ver con la hora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toma en cuenta que Oracle no tiene un tipo que represente solamente una hora. Por esta razón, cuando usas `to_date(campo_hora, 'HH24:MI')` (asumo que algo así debistes hacer), Oracle no solo te puede devolver la hora, sino que te devuelve también una fecha.  Y por defecto, te devolverá el primer día del mes corriente.

Por ejemplo, si ejecutas la sentencia siguiente, tomando en cuenta que la fecha hoy es `2016-11-25`:

```
select to_date('23:30', 'HH24:MI') from dual
```

... te devolverá la siguiente fecha: `2016-11-01 23:30:00`.

Ahora bien, si tu objetivo es de comparar la porción *hora* del `sysdate` con tu campo, necesitas convertir tu campo a una fecha que tenga el mismo día que `sysdate` para que la diferencia sea solamente con la hora. Esto lo puedes lograr de esta manera (asumiendo que `campo_hora` contiene el valor `'23:30'`):

```
select to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || campo_hora, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
  from dual
```

...asumiendo que ejecutas la sentencia hoy (`2016-11-25`), el resultado será la fecha siguiente: `2016-11-25 23:30:00`.

Ahora sí puedes comparar esa fecha con `sysdate` para obtener la diferencia de horas.

Por ejemplo, ahora puedes hacer:

```
select to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || campo_hora, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
       - sysdate
  from dual
```

... lo que te devolverá una decimal que representa la diferencia en cantidad de días, algo como: `0.60605...`, o sea, una fracción de un día.

Ahora la pregunta es saber en qué formato deseas ver la diferencia, puesto que no lo especificastes. Pero digamos que quieres ver la diferencia en horas, entonces tienes que multiplicar por `24`:

```
select (to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || campo_hora, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
       - sysdate) * 24
  from dual
```

... o si quieres ver la diferencia en minutos, entonces hay que multiplicar por `24 * 60`:

```
select (to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' ' || campo_hora, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
       - sysdate) * 24 * 60
  from dual
```

... y así por el estilo para segundos también...

---

Otra opción es que Oracle también tiene un tipo para representar intervalos. Se llama [`INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00221). Si te interesa trabajar con este tipo, entonces puedes hacer una consulta como la siguiente:

```
select TO_DSINTERVAL('0 ' || campo_hora || ':00')
       - NUMTODSINTERVAL(sysdate - trunc(sysdate), 'day')
  from dual
```

Si ejecutas la consulta a las 9:40am mas o menos, esto te devolverá un valor parecido a: `+00 13:50:30.000000`, que representa una diferencia de 13 horas, 50 minutos, 30 segundos, etc.

Comment: Gracias, esta muy clara la respuesta n.n

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente, si tienes almacenado sólo la hora, minuto y segundo en un campo de tu base de datos, tendrías que añadirle la hora en un `to_date`

```
to_date(to_char(sysdate,'dd/mm/yyyy')||campo_hora, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

De esta forma si le restas con el `sysdate`, Oracle te devolverá en días.

```
 select to_date(to_char(sysdate,'dd/mm/yyyy')||campo_hora, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') - sysdate 
from dual
```

Ahora es un tema de si necesitas la diferencia en horas, minutos o segundos. Te dejo el ejemplo para verlo en minutos.

```
select (to_date(to_char(sysdate,'dd/mm/yyyy')||campo_hora, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') - sysdate)*24*60, sysdate, to_date(to_char(sysdate,'dd/mm/yyyy')||campo_hora, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
 from dual
```

Puedes truncar o redondear el resultado de acuerdo a lo que necesites. Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
c_d_registro,
--to_date(c_d_registro,'dd/mm/yyyy')
--to_char(to_date(c_d_registro,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') ,
to_char(to_date(c_d_registro,'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'dd/mm/yyyy') as fecha_registro
FROM sigarp.devolucion_solicitud
WHERE TO_DATE(SUBSTR(c_d_registro,1,10), 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN  TO_DATE('02/02/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('04/02/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: Considera leer [answer], los aportes que son solo código se consideran de baja calidad